# ListObject Date filter settings

Tags: excel, vba

Newer Excel programs (I am using 2013) have very useful filters. I would like to know how to access the current filter setting's StartDate and EndDate in vba code.

Thanks!

[image]

I do see `xlFilterThisWeek`. I can imagine digging up the logic to go from there to write a bunch of code to get at the dates but it *seems* like a fair and useful thing to short circuit the effort if it is well known.

```
Sub spud()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        xlFilterThisWeek, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
End Sub
```

Comment: Record a macro and look at the code that's generated when you do this manually.

Comment: Yes, agreed. Please see edit.